# Get and set data on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

How can I store some data on Google App Engine?  I'm using Django.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to just write web form pages to do this, you might want to take a look at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html which explains a few different ways to import/export data from the appengine datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google app engine helper. Django cannot understand google app engine so you can use this helper to make the Django understand app engine and you are good to go..
http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/